# "Stairs" in Latex table, (some kind of vertical \cline)

Tags: tables, vertical, cline

I want to create such table:

[image]

But the only thing I created is:

[image]

Because I don't know how to make some kind of vertical `\cline`. Please, help.

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\vdots}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, very simple, and worked!

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\vdots}
```

in the cells that need a vertical line

Answer (score 9):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|cccc|}[cell-space-top-limit=3pt]
\Hline
P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} & P_{14} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} & P_{14} \\
\Hline
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (5-|1) -| (4-|2) -| (3-|4) -- (3-|5) ; 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]